# Function returning a null array on one PC, but a filled one on two other

Tags: java

I am running this code in a larger project to search a folder for xml files and return me an array of them.

```
public File[] finder( String dirName){
            File dir = new File(dirName);

            return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { 
                     public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
                          { return filename.endsWith(".xml"); }
            });
        }
```

However. I keep a GitHub repository of my project up so that I can sync my progress between multiple machines and collaborate with others. I wrote this portion of the project, and its related parts, on my desktop where it works just fine. After pulling it to my laptop, however, the function returns a null value. GitHub repo here: https://github.com/AaronSigal/LibGDX-Practice (check the test_aaron branch).

What are some potential causes of this behavior? I had someone clone the repository and pull the branch with that function, and they verified that it was working correctly for them.

Comment: Sounds like the dirname being passed might not be right on every machine maybe? I don't see any way the function itself would be written wrong, check your parameters

Comment: This function depends on external filesystem, so you must check if the actual directory in each machine contains any file matching your filter. One important thing to take into account is that some filesystems are case sensitive. so filename.toLowercase().endsWith(".xml") is a good idea.

Comment: For context, this is where the code is in his repo: https://github.com/AaronSigal/LibGDX-Practice/blob/test_aaron/Lootly/core/src/com/roguelike/lootly/io/StrategyLoadItems.java#L72

Comment: Please, create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will make it much easier to reproduce your problem. This should be relatively easy to do: just move this method to a new project and hardcode the `dirName`.

Comment: Debugging suggestion: check out the return value of `dir.getAbsolutePath()` and make sure that this path actually exists.

Comment: The dirname being passed is "config/". Its a subfolder of "/assets" which is set as a source folder in my eclipse build path settings.

EDIT: So it seems that on my laptop, passing in "/config" leads to "C:\Dev\LibGDX-Practice\Lootly\desktop\config". It essentially misses the \assets\ folder. The path should be "C:\Dev\LibGDX-Practice\Lootly\desktop\assets\config". This is odd, since this argument works perfectly fine on several other machines.